# composer installation using composer not working

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I am trying to install laravel using composer

composer global require "laravel/installer"

but i get [image]

I just finished reinstall my windows 7, before that laravel installation was always succesful and now it is not.. maybe someone know how solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Laravel's Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3#installing-laravel)

Make sure to place the `$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin` directory (or the equivalent directory for your OS) in your $PATH so the laravel executable can be located by your system.
In case of Windows you should ad that $PATH to your enviornment variables.

Comment: This path appears only after succesful laravel downloading using composer, but in my situation download is unsuccessful, so further actions isn't important for a while.
Thanks for effort, but this answer isn't solution